# How should I be using rpcbind and rpcallowip (bitcoin.conf)

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin.conf

I have been very confused on how to use the `rpcbind` and `rpcallowip` arguments for bitcoind. I have a bitcoin core node running on a raspberrypi and I want it to accept json-rpc calls from one of my other devices (connected to the same network as the node). I know I need to use `rpcbind` and `rpcallowip` inside of my bitcoin.conf file, but I don't quite understand how. What values should I give to these paramaters? I also already set `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` inside of the configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the local IP address of rpi using `ifconfig`. Let's assume the IP address is `192.168.1.25`.

Use these values in bitcoin.conf:

```
rpcbind=192.168.1.25
rpcallowip=192.168.1.1/24
```

Comment: This works great! However, when I try to send a post request using curl to the address, nothing returns... (```curl http://<pi's ip adress>:8332/```) @Lemon